# How to get the Hero in Suikoden 1 to join the party?

Tags: suikoden-2

In Suikoden 2, is it possible to get the Hero from the first Suikoden to join the party? If yes, how and when can we do it?

Comment: It's been too long and I forgot the details, but somewhere all the way up north there's a foresty dungeon that leads to the hometown of Suikoden 1's hero. If you meet him, he'll join your party (but dismissing him causes him to go back home and you'll have to do the entire trip again). Don't recall exactly where though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a guide on [GameFAQs](http://www.gamefaqs.com/ps/198844-suikoden-ii/faqs/4783). There seem to be some heavy spoilers, so just a small snippet

> It's true that you can use everyone's lovable Suikoden 1 hero in Suikoden 2.
>   And, if you play your cards right, you can even see
>   Gremio as well.  You must have Suikoden 1 to even attempt this.
>
> There are some things you need to take care of first in Suikoden 1 however.  The thing that is definitely required is your 
>   saved game must be at the last save point in Gregminster before you
>   battle the Golden Hydra.